# Retrieving image from SQLite, “Invalid or Unsupported Image Format”

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, binary, blob

I am using Cloud9 IDE and I am getting an `"Invalid or Unsupported Image Format"` when I open an image stored and retrieved in SQLite. When I input the `convertToBinaryData` file into the `writeTofile` function then the photo is retrieved so this is definitely something to do with the SQL.

Can someone assist in formatting this correctly?

```
def convertToBinaryData(filename):
#Convert digital data to binary format
with open(path, 'rb') as file:
    blobData = file.read()
return blobData

def writeTofile(data, filename):
# Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    advert = file.write(data)

@app.route("/place", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def place():
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("place.html")

if request.method == "POST":
```

I have tried the follow four options and none of them work.

```
'''Version 1'''
    placing = "INSERT INTO food (category, title, description, shipping, photo, county, area, post_time, UID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)"
    ad_photo = convertToBinaryData(request.form.get("photo"))

    db.execute(placing, (session["user_id"], request.form.get("category"), request.form.get("title"), request.form.get("description"), request.form.getlist("option[]"), ad_photo, request.form.get("county"), request.form.get("area")))

    row = db.execute('SELECT photo FROM food')
    print (str(row[0]))
    writeTofile(row[0], "dan.jpg")
```

ERROR:     file.write(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'

```
'''Version 2'''
    placing = "INSERT INTO food (category, title, description, shipping, photo, county, area, post_time, UID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)"
    ad_photo = convertToBinaryData(request.form.get("photo"))
    db.execute(placing, (session["user_id"], request.form.get("category"), request.form.get("title"), request.form.get("description"), request.form.getlist("option[]"), ad_photo, request.form.get("county"), request.form.get("area")))

    row = db.execute('SELECT photo FROM food')
    print (row[0])
    writeTofile(row[0], "dan.jpg")
```

ERROR:  file.write(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'

```
'''Version 3'''
    placing = "INSERT INTO food (UID, category, title, description, shipping, photo, county, area, post_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
    ad_photo = convertToBinaryData(request.form.get("photo"))
    db.execute(placing, (session["user_id"], request.form.get("category"), request.form.get("title"), request.form.get("description"), request.form.getlist("option[]"), ad_photo, request.form.get("county"), request.form.get("area")))

    row = db.execute('SELECT photo FROM food')
    print (str(row[0]))
    mystring = str(row[0])
    b = mystring.encode('utf-8')
    writeTofile(b, "dan.jpg")
```

ERROR: no error but JPEG that is created is "Invalid or Unsupported Image Format"

```
'''Version 4'''
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

    placing = "INSERT INTO food (category, title, description, shipping, photo, county, area, post_time, UID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)"
    ad_photo = convertToBinaryData(request.form.get("photo"))

    # Convert data into tuple format
    data_tuple = (request.form.get("category"), request.form.get("title"), request.form.get("description"), request.form.get("option[]"), ad_photo, request.form.get("county"), request.form.get("area"), session["user_id"])
    cursor.execute(placing, data_tuple)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Image and file inserted successfully as a BLOB into a table")

    cursor.execute("SELECT photo from food")
    record = cursor.fetchone()

    writeTofile(record, "dan.jpg")
    cursor.close()
```

ERROR: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

Comment: Converting it to utf8 is pretty strange if it's suppose to be a binary blob

Comment: When I write
`row = db.execute('SELECT * FROM food') 
writeTofile(row[0], "dan.jpg")`
I get an `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'` error which is why I thought it might be the brackets and why I tried  the `utf-8`.

Comment: Skimming the documentation, it looks like you should be using a `fetchone()` method to get a row from the cursor returned by `db.execute()`?  And then get the appropriate column value out of it? I'm not really familiar with python.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well as fetchall(), still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out after writing out all of my errors and then trying something completely different. Thanks for the sounding board.

```
def place():
"""place an ad"""
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("place.html")

if request.method == "POST":

    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

    placing = "INSERT INTO food (category, title, description, shipping, photo, county, area, post_time, uid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)"
    ad_photo = convertToBinaryData(request.form.get("photo"))

    # Convert data into tuple format
    data_tuple = ((request.form.get("category"), request.form.get("title"), request.form.get("description"), request.form.get("option[]"), ad_photo, request.form.get("county"), request.form.get("area"), session["user_id"]))
    cursor.execute(placing, data_tuple)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Image and file inserted successfully as a BLOB into a table")

    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM food ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 1")

    for row in query:
        pic = row[4]
        writeTofile(pic, "dan.jpg")
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    cursor.close()

return render_template("placed.html")
```